# required "=" in same position in each line in string with str_pad

Tags: php

i have follwing string

```
$string ='
            $PropMap["admin_id"]                = array("Field", "admin_id", "admin_id", "int");
            $PropMap["superadmin"]              = array("Field", "superadmin", "superadmin", "int");
            $PropMap["username"]                = array("Field", "username", "username", "string");
            $PropMap["password"]                = array("Field", "password", "password", "string");
            $PropMap["mail_id"]                 = array("Field", "mail_id", "mail_id", "string");
            $PropMap["master_password"]                 = array("Field", "master_password", "master_password", "string");
            $PropMap["group_id"]                = array("Field", "group_id", "group_id", "int");            
            $PropMap["total"]               = array("Field", "total", "total", "int");';
```

i want to

```
        $result ='                          
        $PropMap["admin_id"]                = array("Field", "admin_id", "admin_id", "int");
        $PropMap["superadmin"]              = array("Field", "superadmin", "superadmin", "int");
        $PropMap["username"]                = array("Field", "username", "username", "string");
        $PropMap["password"]                = array("Field", "password", "password", "string");
        $PropMap["mail_id"]                 = array("Field", "mail_id", "mail_id", "string");
        $PropMap["master_password"]         = array("Field", "master_password", "master_password", "string");
        $PropMap["group_id"]                = array("Field", "group_id", "group_id", "int");            
        $PropMap["total"]                   = array("Field", "total", "total", "int");';
```

means **required "=" in same position in each line**

Comment: backspace? What exactly is the question/problem?

Comment: use `\t` in this case instead of spaces

Answer (score 2):

in order to do that just **pad** you first string (`$PropMap["admin_id"]`) to right for a fixed length.

e.g.,

```
$pad = str_pad($input, $padlength, ' ', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
```

then concatenate it with the rest of the string as

```
$pad.= '= array();';
```